# Do you still score a Go if you end with a pair or sequence?

Tags: cribbage

While playing Cribbage with a new acquaintance, I led the 9H he played 6D for 15-2 I followed with the 10H for 25, Pone called GO. I then played the 2H and 2D for 29, then called Go.   I then counted two for the pair of 2s and one for go.   He argued that after a pair or sequence to end the play you could not count the one for go.  Is there such a rule that I may have missed?

Answer (score 4):

You get one point because he called "Go", not because you played the last card(s).

http://www.bicyclecards.com/card-games/rule/cribbage:

> If a player cannot add another card without exceeding 31, he or she
>   says "Go" and the opponent pegs 1. After gaining the Go, the opponent
>   must first lay down any additional cards he can without exceeding 31.
>   Besides the point for Go, he may then score any additional points that
>   can be made through pairs and runs (described later). If a player
>   reaches exactly 31, he pegs two instead of one for Go.

Answer (score 0):

Your opponent is incorrect.  You would score the go as well as the pair, just as you did.  Its hard to prove a negative with a rules quote, so I'd say the burden is on your opponent to show anything in the rules that supports his interpretation.